# RRSet with DNS name _acme-challenge.mybar.org. is not permitted in zone bar.org. while letsencrypt certificate generation

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53, lets-encrypt

I have two domain names in aws route53:

```
 bar.org
 mybar.org
```

i am trying to generate Letsencrypt certificate using ruby based hook of dns-01 challenge ( https://gist.github.com/joshgarnett/02920846fea35f738d3370fd991bb0e0)

I am generating certificate for the domain "mybar.org", so my domains.txt contains the name as:

```
mybar.org
```

when i try to run dehydrated -c i get the following error:

```
RRSet with DNS name _acme-challenge.mybar.org. is not permitted in zone bar.org.
```

why does it try to add RRSet in bar.org instead of mybar.org? How do i get it working?

Comment: why is this down voted, check my answer as this is a real issue to be solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ruby based dns hook linked in the question has a bug at the following line at find_hosted_zone function while finding the hosted zone index out of available Route53 zones.

> index = hosted_zones.index { |zone| domain.end_with?(zone.name.chop)
>   }

index is derived based on the zone ends with the give domain name. Since my domain name "mybar.org" evaluates to true with "bar.org" (other available zone), it returns index of that zone. So this needs a PR to solve the issue.

in my case it worked fine while i modified the code as:

> index = hosted_zones.index { |zone| zone.name.chop.end_with?(domain)
>   }